# REGEX find words in upper case and words followed by a single special character

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone help me. I'm trying to parse this string using regex in javascript:

`BMB-001 RING/MESH T-Bar Track T-BAR W/`

My Goal is to match `RING`, `MESH`, `T-BAR` and `W/` only.

I'm currently using this regex:
`(\b[^\d\W][A-Z-'\/]['A-Z]+|\b[A-Z][-\/$])`, But the result matched `BMB`, `RING`, `MESH`, `T-B`,`T-BAR` and `W/`

Comment: Try `\b[A-Z]+(?:[-'][A-Z]+)*(?:\/|(?!\S))`, see https://regex101.com/r/0APlTi/2

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you post this as an answer so I could accept it gladly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\b[A-Z]+(?:[-'][A-Z]+)*(?:\/|(?!\S))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0APlTi/2). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Z]+` - one or more uppercase letters
- `(?:[-'][A-Z]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of `-` or `'` and one or more uppercase letters
- `(?:\/|(?!\S))` - a `/` or a location not immediately followed with a non-whitespace char.